# Using /clr and noclr libraries in one project

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, clr, managed-c++, tetgen

I am encountering some issues with one project. I need to use two libraries but one needs to be compiled with the `/clr` switch as the other cannot be compiled with this switch.

Would there be a way to use at the same time those two libraries in one project? Currently it's compiled with `/clr` and I got linking errors with the `noclr` library.

If there is no solution I can still launch the `noclr` library in batchmode but I'd like to avoid it...

My project is in Managed C++, the library [tetgen](http://tetgen.berlios.de/) - which needs /clr - is in **native** C++ and cannot be compiled without the /clr switch, as I get this error

> error C3381: 'tetgenio' : assembly access specifiers are only available in code compiled with a /clr option

The other library [triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) is in C. I am on Visual Studio 2008 and the project is compiled in 32 bits.

Comment: Can you give us more details about your project? i.e. Language? Platform? etc..

Comment: The extra details is till pretty thin. Is tetgen native or managed? Please use an overabundance of details, NOT a minimum.

Comment: Tell me if you need something else, I cannot think of something to add.

Comment: Did you mean to put a comma after /clr? Without it, the meaning of your sentence is ambiguous. Is library tetgen native, or your 'project' managed. Or is tetgen managed, and tetgen native?

Comment: Yes I meant. Tetgen is in Native c++, my project in managed.

Comment: You've got linker errors.  Post the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use more details, but using managed C++ you can certainly use a mix of managed and unmanaged code. (Microsoft calls their managed c++ code C++/CLI.)

EDIT:

Ok, your compiler error helped. Apparently you have specified a native class, but using public private, or some other access specifier on the name of the native class. From the MSDN docs:

The following sample generates C3381:

```
// C3381.cpp
**public** class A {   // C3381. Remove public or make the class
managed. }; 
int main() { }
```

so get rid of the public keyword, and then try compiling again.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple projects in a single solution.  Right click on the solution in the eolution explorer and add -> existing/new project.  Each library project can be added that way and have their own clr settings.

Comment: This project is actually part of a 10-project solution. I just cannot link the noclr library to my project, I got some linking errors. I have tried to link this library to a project I created, not compiled with /clr and containing only  call to its functions and it works. Then when I link this intermediate project to my initial project, the compiler says it cannot find the header to the noclr library in the intermediate project.